# HeroCard Action does not work in MS Teams iOS from version 2.0.10 updated May 8 2020

Tags: c#, ios, botframework, microsoft-teams

### Describe the bug

I'm using botframwork to build company bot chat using MS Teams channel, recently after our user updated MS Teams client on iOS device to version 2.0.10 from Appstore, the herocard action does not work anymore. (It worked well before updating)

My code:

```
            var card = new HeroCard {
                Subtitle = $"You can use below buttons to get started:",
                Buttons = new List<CardAction> () {
                    new CardAction () {
                        Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
                        Title = "Check in",
                        Text = "Check in",
                        Value = "Check in"
                    },
                    new CardAction () {
                        Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
                        Title = "Check out",
                        Text = "Check out",
                        Value = "Check out"
                    }
                }
            };

            var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment (card.ToAttachment ());
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync (activity, cancellationToken);
```

### Expected behavior

Type = ActionTypes.PostBack - When tapping any button, a message will be posted to chat.

### Actual behavior

Type = ActionTypes.PostBack - When tapping any button, message was not posted to chat.

### Screenshots

[image: IMG_1920]

### Additional context

- Try to change ActionTypes to MessageBack, ImBack also won't work.
- This issue is happened only on iOS Teams client. It's ok on Android, desktop, browser Teams clients.

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2398

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say it "does not work anymore"? Describe your expected behavior versus the actual behavior. Is it possible that the bot is receiving a message without text that is not displayed in the conversation history?

Comment: @TienVn Thanks for reporting the issue. We have created a bug for this and will be working on it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report and not a question

Comment: This bug is fixed. Please update to the latest version and check

Answer (score 0):

You can raise the bug through the Teams app itself. There is also a UserVoice forum you can use: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/908686-bug-reports/category/327013-client-ios